# Using Pandas, groupby and get top n values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
Serial     Value
1          21.10
1          43.06
1          32.12
2          11.20
2          22.20
3          45.10
3          14.16
```

I would like to get identify the maximum Value for each Serial and did this by,

```
df['Max'] = df.groupby('Serial')['Value'].transform('max')
df['Max'] = df['Max'].mask(df['Serial'].duplicated(), '') # to only show first values of each Serial group
print(df)
Serial     Value     Max
1          21.10     43.06
1          43.06
1          32.12
2          11.20     22.20
2          22.20
3          45.10     45.10
3          14.16
```

Now, I would like to get the top 2 values of Max column and replace it with Serial values

```
Serial     Value     Max      Top_Serial
1          21.10     43.06    3
1          43.06              1
1          32.12
2          11.20     22.20
2          22.20
3          45.10     45.10
3          14.16
```

I tried `df['Top_Serial'] = df.groupby('Serial')['Max'].nlargest(2)` but I got this error 
`TypeError: Cannot use method 'nlargest' with dtype object`

Thank you

Comment: yes. i'd just like to identify the top 2 Serials that has the highest Max values –

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible approach:

```
df['Max'] = df.groupby('Serial')['Value'].transform('max')
# You need to have numerical values for nlargest to work!
df['Max'] = df['Max'].mask(df['Serial'].duplicated(), 0)

df['Top_Serial'] =( df.loc[df.Max.nlargest(2).index, 'Serial']
                      .reset_index(drop=True)
                      .reindex(df.index)
                      .fillna(''))

df['Max'] = df.Max.mask(df.Max.eq(0), '')
```

---

```
print(df)

   Serial  Value    Max Top_Serial
0       1  21.10  43.06          3
1       1  43.06                 1
2       1  32.12                  
3       2  11.20   22.2           
4       2  22.20                  
5       3  45.10   45.1           
6       3  14.16
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier not to correlate your final column with the rest of the data, i.e. There really isn't a correlation between the "Top_Serial" column and the "Serial" column in terms of indexing.

Maybe something like this?

```
>>> list(df.groupby('Serial').max().sort_values('Value').index[:2])
[2, 1]
```